# Can we store and read keys in Fido2 device (yubikey)

Tags: react-native, webauthn, fido, fido-u2f, yubikey

I am working on an android and iOS application that needs to have a password-less solution for login. We are trying to implement WebAuthn/Fido2 device.

The problem is that Fido is still new and there is no React-Native library that implements that. So I have a few questions regarding it.

Can we read and write our own key in the Fido2 device?
=> Till we get a proper library, I want to store an encrypted password on the fido2 device as a key, read it every time on login, and decrypt it. Is it sounds good to implement and is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

@DevPy

To support WebAuthn/FIDO2 from your React Native iOS application, the recommended solution is to integrate one of two Apple iOS system browsers ([ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession) or [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)) that support WebAuthn APIs. ASWebAuthenticationSession would be my first choice as this browser is for authentication through a web service, specifically the OAuth 2 flow. This provides the interface, built-in APIs for interacting with the FIDO2 authenticator, like the YubiKey, and gives the developer control with callback to the session and authentication token. Another way to integrate WebAuthn is to utilize a third-party SDK for communicating with OAuth 2 providers. For example, [AppAuth for iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) has a React Native bridge, available [here](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth). I believe the AppAuth SDK uses the ASWebAuthenticationSession.

As for the initial question of writing/reading your own custom key, the FIDO2 devices are limited in storage space but the YubiKey offers two options that may work for you. One is the option to create a [static password](https://www.yubico.com/resources/glossary/static-password/) (not encrypted) or utilize the [Yubico OTP](https://developers.yubico.com/OTP/OTPs_Explained.html). Both options use the system keyboard to type out the password or OTP into any text/password field within your app. No SDK or system browser required.

Answer (score 0):

FIDO2/WebAuthn is specifically a browser API. Since you're talking about authentication within a (React) native app then you'll probably want to fall back to equivalent native OS API's instead.

For Android you can use the `Fido2ApiClient`, which will let you leverage existing FIDO2 credentials on your server for in-app authentication:

- https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fido/fido2/Fido2ApiClient

I think the equivalent on the iOS side of native app development is Authentication Service. They have a page specifically about leveraging "passkeys" in your app that will probably help get you started:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/public-private_key_authentication

Comment: Hi Kale, thanks for the links that really helps, but all this need to be implemented to react native, so for quick solution I am thinking to wrap my login page as webview to login using webauthn. Do you know any way to do that or return to main app when login is successful

Comment: Ah, no, unfortunately I don't have any experience with that.